# Pseudo selector .classname:not(:hover) {} not applying styles to previous elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I will try to make this easy as possible to understand.

**Goal:**
All .hover-section not hovered will have opacity of 0.5.

**Currently:**
All .hover-section elements after the hovered .hover-section have opacity: 0.5, but the previous .hover-section have opacity of 0. I'm thinking I have a two classes applying an opacity but can't seem to find it or maybe I have it structured incorrectly.

Would greatly appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance!

**Codepen:**

```
.container:hover .hover-section:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

https://codepen.io/garynorris88/pen/EXPavg?editors=1100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `z-index` on `.background` is covering all of the previous elements. Use a negative `z-index` instead to push that element behind the parent and the content in the previous sibling `.hover-section`s will display.

```css
.body {
  height: 300px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #111;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

#alpha .background {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000/1000");
}
#alpha:hover .background {
  opacity: 1;
}

#bravo .background {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000/1000");
}
#bravo:hover .background {
  opacity: 1;
}

#charlie .background {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000x1000");
}
#charlie:hover .background {
  opacity: 1;
}

#delta .background {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/g/1000/1008");
}
#delta:hover .background {
  opacity: 1;
}

.background {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

.hover-section {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 !important;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.3s;
  width: 25%;
}
.hover-section h1 {
  z-index: 2;
}

.content {
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.content:before {
  background-color: #333;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.content:hover:before {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container:hover .hover-section:not(:hover) .content {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hover-section" id="alpha">
      <div class='background'></div>
      <div class='content'>
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div >
  </div>
  <div class="hover-section" id="bravo">
      <div class='background'></div>
      <div class='content'>
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div >
  </div>
  <div class="hover-section" id="charlie">
      <div class='background'></div>
      <div class='content'>
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div >
  </div>
  <div class="hover-section" id="delta">
      <div class='background'></div>
      <div class='content'>
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Also do you know what is causing that flicker of the previous elements when hover the items on the right?

Comment: @Gary you bet :) Hmm... not sure, I'm about to head out for a little bit but will look at it when I get back.

Comment: Ok much appreciated Michael!

Comment: @Gary looks like it's from toggling the background opacity. If you limit the `.contaner:hover .hover-section:not(:hover)` selector to target `.content`, the flicker goes away. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Gary here's a pen with your SCSS if you want that https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/qjQpOW?editors=1100